# Please help on this cable conections

Tags: wiring, timer

I have a 2 water pump and a controller with a timer that need to be connected. The controller had two outlets for the pumps, and in the back has 3 terminals: HOT Neutral HOT.

But my 240 volt supply just has 2 hot cables but not neutral so how can I supply the neutral pole on the controller if I only have 2 hot lines?

Comment: It would be helpful to have the make / model number of the timer

Comment: Intermatic does still make a mechanical timer with a 240v clock motor which doesn't need a neutral to operate.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small load like a timer motor, the appliance could be "hacked" by adding a tiny 240/120v transformer to produce the 120V within the appliance.

I would consult with the factory to see exactly how they use 120V within the appliance and if they have any sanctioned kit or instructions to do just that.

---

Very often, 240V appliances have some control that is 120V.  When they sell that same appliance in East Asia, which is all 240V-only, they add a tiny 120V transformer just as I describe.    That "East Asian" spec is perfectly compatible with US power and they could market them here... but they want to pinch pennies, so they remove the $2 transformer and require a neutral.

So if it's possible to convert the appliance to East Asian spec, that may be cheaper than running new cable with neutral.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a new cable with 4 conductors - 2 hot, 1 neutral and 1 ground.  A new install would be configured this way but your current setup is common with older homes.

The only other alternative would be to find a new pump that only needs the two hot lines.

Comment: Thank but is the timer that has 3 cables not the pump, can i run a single line to neutral??

Comment: No this is generally not permitted

Comment: @Christ2000 only if the "hot" wires are individual wires in conduit.  If they are a multiconductor cable such as NM or SE, you cannot add a neutral.  All hots and neutral must run together in the same cable or conduit.